# Recognize if the client is requesting page or something else in ASP.NET MVC custom HttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, httpmodule

I have written custom `HttpModule` that does something every time `RequestEnd` event gets fired.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    context.EndRequest += EndEventHandler;
}
```

But I want it to do something only when `EndRequest` event is fired for the request of a html page. Not when it is a request for `CSS` file, picture or something else. How can I recognize what kind of content is being requested in that particular request so that I can decide what to do ?

---

*Note: I guess similar question has been asked before but I cannot find it please add to possible duplicates if you can.*

---

**EDIT:** To be more exact, I want to take some steps during the end of request if that request was processed by controller action (hmm when I think about it now maybe action filter that gets called for all actions would be better then module - is there some kind of filter that is not called when redirect action is returned?).

Comment: what are you trying to do after every request and why? that may help us to determine if there's another way or a better way to accomplish your end-goal.

Comment: @George Stocker I'm saving some data about request to tha database for dataminig... Like browser, whether it is authenticated user or anonymous...

Comment: @George Stocker so do you think there is better way ?

Comment: Darin already posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can look at the content type:</strike>

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType == "text/html")
{
    ... you will be returning an HTML
}
```

or if you want to restrict only to static HTML pages you could also look at the request:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".html"))
{
    ... it was a static html page that was requested
}
```

UPDATE:

Alright, I've just noticed that your question was tagged with `asp.net-mvc`. At first when I saw an HttpModule I thought you were doing a normal ASP.NET application (I couldn't even imagine an HttpModule in an MVC application).

Now that this has been clear you obviously could use a [global action filter](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/global-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) in which you can override the `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` methods which will be invoked respectively before and after a controller action is executed.

As far as your question about the redirect action in the OnActionExecuted method you could look at the `filterContext.Result` and see if it is a `RedirectToRouteResult` type:

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        if (!(filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned that such method exists... 2 questions: 1. Is this always going to work ? 2. Is it the right way to do it ? What I'm really trying to do is explained in second comment under my original question.

Comment: No I don't really have static html in my application. I want to respond with some "logging" action on all requests that are going to be handled by Controller actions. This is good formulation I'll add it to question.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov +1 Great update. So this is the right way to do some information gathering about the request, right ?

Comment: @drasto, yes, action filters are definitely the correct way to run some custom code at different moments of the execution of the MVC pipeline.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov "different moments of the execution of the MVC pipeline"? I thought that action filters can be only executed before and after any controller action?

Comment: @drasto, no, also before and after the action result is executed (`OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted`).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Thank you. I'll accept your answer in few hours.